# User ID in MVC5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Do user ID in database, built by default by Identity and

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()
```

have similar value?

Comment: I don't know, do they? Have you tested it? It probably depends on how you've got your application set up in relation to logins etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously have same value user ID in database built by default of type `Uniqueidentifier` and this identity code `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()` is just getting
the current Users Id that is already stored in database..